# Enable all Firefox extensions in private mode by default

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I am trying to enable all extensions in private mode in Firefox without having to go into each addon. Is there a universal switch (or extension) of sorts that does this in one go?

I tried [this](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/02/01/firefox-will-soon-disallow-extensions-in-private-mode-by-default/) but it is not working as expected. Extensions are still off in private mode.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This used to be possible by setting in `about:config` the option on
`extensions.allowPrivateBrowsingByDefault` to true.

However, the Firefox developers have recently decided to remove the
feature.

In the article
[These Weeks in Firefox: Issue 96](https://blog.nightly.mozilla.org/2021/06/23/these-weeks-in-firefox-issue-96/),
it's said:

> **Sonia Singla** contributed a patch to remove the about:config preference “extensions.allowPrivateBrowsingByDefault” (it has been introduced as a fallback mechanism to return to the older behavior, during the transition to the user-controlled extension permission to selectively allow extensions to run in private windows) – [Bug 1661517](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1661517)

This same question was raised several times by users since then,
but didn't find a sympathetic ear with the developers.

Negative answer: This is no longer possible, and it's by design,
unfortunately.

Comment: How the mighty have fallen. Would you say Waterfox or Basilisk would be an alternative or are they fated to the same path?

Comment: These Firefox clones follow their own paths, taking new features from Firefox only when they suit their view of the browser. I cannot answer whether they will follow Firefox in the future or not.

Comment: Firefox developers have made many decisions that drove away many users, myself included.

Comment: would you mind if ask what browser you're using or would recommend? Since I'm in the market for one because of Mozilla's shenanigans.

Comment: I'm using Palemoon because it still supports the legacy add-ons that I like.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to enable all extensions in private mode, programmatically through the Browser Console.

First [enable the command line of the Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console)

Then execute the following snippet

```javascript
(async()=>{
    const PRIVATE_BROWSING_PERMS = {
        permissions: ["internal:privateBrowsingAllowed"],
        origins: [],
    };
    const {ExtensionPermissions} = ChromeUtils.import("resource://gre/modules/ExtensionPermissions.jsm");
    const myaddons = await AddonManager.getAddonsByTypes(["extension"]);
    for(let addon of myaddons){
        let policy = WebExtensionPolicy.getByID(addon.id);
        let extension = policy && policy.extension;
        await ExtensionPermissions.add(addon.id, PRIVATE_BROWSING_PERMS, extension);
        if (addon.isActive)
            addon.reload();
    }
})();
```

**Warning**: Code executed from the Browser Console can bypass almost every security barrier. While the above snippet is quite straightforward, if you don't understand what a piece of code does, you should not trust strangers (that's me) telling you it's harmless to execute it from the Browser Console.

Comment: I have never seen such a solution for this problem. I am very grateful for the answer. `ctrl+shift+j` opens the browser console for vanilla firefox and firefox developer edition and the code works in them but I don't know how to run the code for firefox nightly since the caret never shows up in the console. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Nightly is no different than release or devedition, in fact it is more permissive. Did you enable the command line?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by editing `extension-preferences.json` in your Firefox profile. Here's mine:

```
{
  -- snip (a bunch of built-in extensions) --
  "uBlock0@raymondhill.net": {
    "permissions": [
      "internal:privateBrowsingAllowed"
    ],
    "origins": []
  }
}
```

Just add that permission to all of the extension entries (you could probably create a `sed` to automate this, or even just parse the JSON).

I hope Mozilla considers bringing back the `extensions.allowPrivateBrowsingByDefault` option. Their removal of it is complete security theater and won't stop any bad actors from programmatically enabling a malicious extension in private mode. What it does accomplish is making the job of sysadmins more difficult. It's also worth mentioning that I was able to find this out in all of 2 minutes by diffing (using Meld) the before and after of my Firefox profile - so I really hope this wasn't intended as a security barrier.